# Некоторые юнит-тесты падают в Azure, но проходят локально (C#, Asp.Net)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, юнит-тесты, azure

В нашем проекте есть сервис, который генерирует PDF-документы. Итак, у нас есть тесты, которые проверяют, равны ли два документа. Первый документ, называемый "Expected", мы уже имеем локально в качестве шаблонного документа. Второй документ, называемый "Actual" или "Result", генерируется автоматически нашим сервисом. Вот код:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void PdfExportProviderTest()
    {
        var document = GetDocument("Pdf document");

        IExportProvider pdfExportProvider = new PDFExportProvider();
        var stream = pdfExportProvider.Export(document, DisplayUnits.Imperial);

        var resultPdf = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
        var expectedPdf = GetPdfByName("ExpectedDocument.pdf");

        Assert.IsTrue(Clear(expectedPdf).Equals(Clear(resultPdf), StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
    }
```

(Метод Clear удаляет всю случайно или динамически сгенерированную информацию из PDF (например, информацию о создании, идентификатор и т.д.)
Как вы можете видеть, мы конвертируем наши PDF-файлы в две строки UTF-8 и сравниваем их. Все тесты успешно проходят локально. Но когда мы запускаем их на Azure, Azure Pipeline генерирует отчет, где некоторые из тестов PDF (не все!) не прошли. То, что я уже пробовал:

1. Приводил результат и фактическую строку к одной кодировке (UTF-8).
2. Удалял скрытые символы с помощью этого выражения: Regex.Replace(text.Trim(), @"[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\u007E]", "*");
3. Я сгенерировал файлы з различиями, чтобы проверить, что не так в Azure, и когда я получил эти сгенерированые файлы, я вижу, что строки, которые должны быть не равны, по факту - равны, хотя мой метод по логике выводит только те строки, которые отличаются (т.е. не равны), остальные он пропускает и не записывает в файл разницы.
4. Я установил второй параметр "StringComparison.CurrentCulter" в методе Equals.
5. Все файлы .cs имеют кодировку UTF-8.

Ничего из выше написанного не помогло. Надеюсь на помощь! Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: С культурой я думаю вы пошли в правильном направлении, только наверняка не до конца: на локальном компе одна культура, допустим русская или украинская, а в Азуре какая?

Comment: попробуйте сравнивать не через `Assert.IsTrue`, а чем-то что выдает дифф, например Shouldly, он покажет где начинается различие, хотя хз, что он покажет на очень больших строках

Comment: Может они действительно не одинаковые и проблема в генерации - скажем, если там в PDF выводятся числа, формат которых зависит от культуры, или даты?

Comment: @Quercus, все даты, которые есть в ПДФ-е я очищаю, да и в дифф-чекере результат, который приходит с Ажура в Пайплайне идентичный тому, что локально - проверял дифф-чекерами, спасибо.

Comment: @AK, спасибо за совет, посмотрю, какая культура на Ажуре)

Comment: Ну это просто самое очевидное, что приходит в голову. Например, дата в локально в русском документе стоит как 17.11.2020, а на Азуре 11/17/2020 - но вы долго будете сверять строчки PDF-документа, пытаясь понять в чём разница. Это же проще посмотреть глазами, визуально сравнива два документа.

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо за помощь! Проблема была в том, что на Ажуре генерировались ПДФ-файлы и при просмотре файлов в текстовом режиме, я установил, что *после каждой строчки добавлялся символ перехода на новую строку с кодом 13 (Carriage Return)*. После того, как я почистил эти символы, всё заработало!

Comment: Видимо, дело в `Environment.NewLine`: на Винде оно равно `\r\n`, на Никсах `\n`.

Comment: Alexander Petrov, да, верно!